# gulp-json-sass - Cannot include json file

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass, gulp-ruby-sass

[Source link](https://github.com/rbalicki2/gulp-json-sass) - I don't know what is missing here

Everything fine if I am not including **json file**

1) gulpfile.js

```
var jsonSass = require('gulp-json-sass'),
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');


    gulp.task('sass', function() {
      return gulp
        .src(['sass/example.json', 'sass/example.scss'])
        .pipe(jsonSass({
          sass: true
        }))
        .pipe(concat('output.scss'))
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('out/'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['sass']);
```

2) example.json

```
{
    "color": "blue"
}
```

3) example.scss file

```
.test{
    color:$color; 
}
```

4) error message
[image]

Comment: Do not post screenshots of code or errors.

Comment: Why any problem here  ?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** You want to output SCSS, not SASS. That means your `sass` option for `gulp-json-sass` is wrong.  From the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-json-sass#sass):

> If truthy, output valid sass variables. If false, output scss variables.

**2.** You can't use `gulp-ruby-sass` in a pipe. From the [docs](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass#sasssource-options):

> Use `gulp-ruby-sass` instead of `gulp.src` to compile Sass files.

That means `.pipe(sass())` won't work. You have to use `gulp-sass` instead of `gulp-ruby-sass`.

```
var jsonSass = require('gulp-json-sass'),
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src(['sass/example.json', 'sass/example.scss'])
    .pipe(jsonSass({
      sass: false 
    }))
    .pipe(concat('output.scss'))
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('out/'));
});
```

Comment: Do you any how to solve "-" issue when writing child json ? https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-json-sass

Comment: No idea what you mean. Create a new question and give a more detailed description of your problem.

Comment: I was asking about json-sass options about "delim" https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-json-sass#jsonsassoptions  , Is it big issue just leave it :) I will add it as another question